# Syntax error at last line (calling function line) while executing python script

Tags: python, automation, pexpect

I'm trying to automate some tasks through a python script which uses pexpect.
I'm also using 2 .sh scripts. 1 which calls this python script and second which launch execution of a binary script.

Here are the files i'm using:

```
root@box: ~# cat while.sh
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do

    ./try $line
done < $1

root@box: ~# cat try
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, pwd, os
sys.path.append('pexpect')
try:
        import pexpect
except(ImportError):
        print "\nYou need the pexpect module."
        sys.exit(1)
#Change this if needed.
LOGIN_ERROR = 'not response! '
def connect(host):
        print "Trying: ",host
        child = pexpect.spawn ('./x '+host)
        child.expect ('Enter string: ')
        child.sendline ('blablastring')
        i = child.expect([LOGIN_ERROR, pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout=10)
        if i  == 1:
                print "\n\t[!] OK:",host
                child.sendline ('echo OK')
                print "\nCommand executed successfully on:",host
                print child.before
                child.interact()
        if i == 0:
                print "Failed to exec cmd on: ",host
if len(sys.argv) != 1:
        print "\nUsage : ./try <host>"
        print "Eg: ./try 1.3.3.7\n"
        sys.exit(1)
target = sys.argv[1]
try:
     connect(host)

root@box: ~# cat x
#!/bin/bash

./somescript -h $1 -d 22
root@box: ~#

root@box: ~# head -n 5 hosts
192.168.1.120
192.168.1.121
192.168.1.122
192.168.1.123
192.168.1.124
root@box: ~#

root@box: ~# sh while.sh hosts
  File "./try", line 34

                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "./try", line 34

                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "./try", line 34

                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "./try", line 34

                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "./try", line 34

root@box: ~#
```

Where is this failing?

Comment: Because you have a `try` without `except`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
try:
   connect(host)
```

This would help:

```
try:
   connect(host)
except Exception:
    pass
```

Comment: `except Exception` is preferable, to avoid catching things like `SystemExit`.

Comment: Yeah. But this was just an example code. Which exception he is trying to catch are he going to choose anyway.

Comment: SystemExit only raise when people are working with sys module. I think you mean the SystemError exception ;). And in his code, sys is only being executed in the begining.

Comment: No, I meant `SystemExit`. That exception, along with `GeneratorExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, and `StopIteration`, are used more for program flow/termination than to signal an actual error condition, and should rarely be caught.

Comment: Now i dont get anymore Syntax error, but somehow script is not doing job properly: root@box: ~# ./try 192.168.0.123

Usage : ./try <target>
Eg: ./try 1.3.3.7

root@box: ~#